# Async task does not end

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, .net-4.5

I'm trying to start async task (on .NET 4.5) which downloads content of web page, but somehow this task never finishes.

My `PageDownloader` class:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

namespace ParserConsole.WebClient
{
public class PageDownloader
{
    private System.Net.Http.HttpClient _client;

    public PageDownloader()
        : this(Encoding.UTF8) { }

    private Encoding _encoding;

    public PageDownloader(Encoding encoding)
    {
        _encoding = encoding;
        _client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)};
    }

    private HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private HttpResponseMessage _response;
    private string _responseString;

    public string GetPageData(string link)
    {
        _request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, link);
        _request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Chrome/21.0.1180.89");
        _request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html");


        GetResponse().Wait();
        GetStringFromResponse().Wait();
        return _responseString;            
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponse() {
        return _response = await _client.GetAsync(_request.RequestUri);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetStringFromResponse() {
        return _responseString = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

}
}
```

I start downloading page by calling

```
new PageDownloader().GetPageData(url);
```

When I'm trying to debug the code, everything is fine till `GetResponse().Wait()`. But somehow  `GetResponse()` task never finishes - breakpoint on the next line is never reached. I get no exceptions, application continues running. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a standard deadlock condition you get when you start an `async` operation and then block on the returned task.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx) is a blog post discussion the topic.

Basically, the `await` call ensures that the continuation it wires up of the task will run in the context you were originally in (which is very helpful) but because you are calling `Wait` in that same context it's blocking, so the continuation never runs, and that continuation needs to run for the wait to end.  Classic deadlock.

As for the fix; usually it means you just shouldn't be doing a blocking wait on the async operation; it's contrary to the design of the whole system.  You should, "async all the way up".  In this case it would mean that `GetPageData` should return a `Task<string>` rather than a `string`, and rather than waiting on the other operations that return a task you should `await` on them.

Now, having said that, there *are* ways of doing a blocking wait on the async operations without deadlocking.  While it can be done, it honestly defeats the purpose of using async/await in the first place.  The primary advantage of using that system is that the main context isn't blocked; when you block on it that entire advantage goes away, and you might as well just use blocking code all the way through.  `async`/`await` is really more of an all-or-nothing paradigm.

Here is how I would structure that class:

```
public class PageDownloader
{
    private System.Net.Http.HttpClient _client;
    private Encoding _encoding;

    public PageDownloader()
        : this(Encoding.UTF8) { }

    public PageDownloader(Encoding encoding)
    {
        _encoding = encoding;
        _client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
    }

    public async Task<string> GetPageData(string link)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, link);
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Chrome/21.0.1180.89");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(request.RequestUri);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Can you also explain how should I handle response in the calling code?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this if you want to have a function like that.

```
public string GetPageData(string link)
{
    _request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, link);
    _request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Chrome/21.0.1180.89");
    _request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html");


    var readTask = _client.GetStringAsync(link);
    readTask.Wait();
    return readTask.Result;
}
```

It would be better to return the Task all the way back and handle it with async/await in the calling code.

```
public Task<string> GetPageData(string link)
{
    _request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, link);
    _request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Chrome/21.0.1180.89");
    _request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html");


    return _client.GetStringAsync(link);
}
```

Comment: How so? I am not starting an async/await prior to the Wait call.  I am using a standard Wait call on the Task.  Maybe I am missing something, but it looks almost identical to the SDK examples of using the Wait method.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, that's correct.  I suppose you could just use the blocking call at that point though.  Also, `Result` blocks, so there's no need (although no problem with) calling `Wait` first.